# Dumping DOM using chrome headless and GO

Tags: go, google-chrome-headless

#### What I am trying to do :

Dump the dom after it is rendered using **chrome headless** and **go**.

I saw over the code of [aqautone](https://github.com/michenriksen/aquatone/blob/master/agents/url_screenshotter.go#L100) to get an idea as to how to use chrome headless for my needs.

#### Problem

The problem is if I add many urls it just time outs printing `Dumping dom timed out` and currently when there's only two urls it prints :

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
Checking  bingBot
1.73 URL : https://www.facebook.com
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
Checking  yahooBot
1.75 URL : https://www.facebook.com
Checking  bingBot
1.74 URL : https://www.google.com
Checking  googleBot
1.75 URL : https://www.google.com
Checking  googleBot
1.76 URL : https://www.facebook.com
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
Checking  yahooBot
1.76 URL : https://www.google.com
Total time taken 1.78s elapsed
```

Here's my go code : [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QZGlztvzlPY)
( However since there's no chrome exec there so it is no point)

In case you don't want to go to the Playground :

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
    "time"
    //"github.com/remeh/sizedwaitgroup"
)

// Taken from https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings
var (
    useragentstrings = map[string]string{
        "googleBot": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)",
        "bingBot":   "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)",
        "yahooBot":  "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)",
    }
    chromePath = "/root/tools/chromium-latest-linux/latest/chrome"
)

func fetchUsingChrome(url string, nameOfAgent string, useragent string, ch chan<- string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    // func fetchUsingChrome(url string, nameOfAgent string, useragent string, ch chan<- string, wg *sizedwaitgroup.SizedWaitGroup) {
    start := time.Now()
    defer wg.Done()
    var chromeArguments = []string{
        "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--hide-scrollbars", "--mute-audio", "--disable-notifications",
        "--disable-crash-reporter",
        "--ignore-certificate-errors",
        "--dump-dom",
        // "--screenshot=" + url + ".png",
        "--user-agent=" + useragent,
    }
    if os.Geteuid() == 0 {
        chromeArguments = append(chromeArguments, "--no-sandbox")
    }
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, chromePath, chromeArguments...)
    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("[%s]Dumping dom failed Error: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    // buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    // if err := buf.ReadFrom(stdout); err != nil {
    // fmt.Println(err)
    // return
    // }
    // fmt.Println(buf.String())
    if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
            fmt.Printf("Dumping dom timed out : %s\n", url)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("[%s]Dumping dom failed Error: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    secs := time.Since(start).Seconds()
    fmt.Println("Checking ", nameOfAgent)
    ch <- fmt.Sprintf("%.2f URL : %s", secs, url)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    output := []string{
        "https://www.facebook.com",
        "https://www.google.com",
    }
    start := time.Now()
    ch := make(chan string)
    //swg := sizedwaitgroup.New(10)
    for _, url := range output {
        for k, v := range useragentstrings {
            wg.Add(1)
            //swg.Add()
            go fetchUsingChrome(url, k, v, ch, &wg)
            // go fetchUsingChrome(url, k, v, ch, &swg)
        }
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        // swg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()
    for val := range ch {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Total time taken %.2fs elapsed\n", time.Since(start).Seconds())
}
```

**P.S.** : I've deliberately left some commented code, to give an insight as to what all I've tried and failed.

Thanks
Temporarya
( A golang noobie )

Comment: Why not increase the timeout? If you do more work in parallel that may take longer. Or just do not that much work in parallel.

Comment: @Volker Thanks for your suggestion but I would like to point out that timeout is the same as in aquatone, so why should it get "timed out" ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to start chrome headless and then use [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) to control the instance you opened on a local machine, but it also works with a remote chrome instance.

You can use this library: https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp

I used this to make screenshots of web pages with Chrome headless which I opened in a docker container.

Here is a little example of what I have done: https://gist.github.com/efimovalex/9f9b815b0d5b1b7889a51d46860faf8a

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as you can see in the [issue 128](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/128), it's still not able to do that, even I had put an answer there but that doesn't work in multithreaded goroutines. However aquatone does it and so I was trying to replicate that functionality in my code.